# How to replace an attribute value with the value of another attribute

Tags: html, jquery

I took `jQuery` multilanguage logic [from this site](https://lang.dev2studio.com/).

Because files with the `.ini` extension are used, script takes the value immediately after the `=` sign.

There is lang folder. Inside it there are 3 lang folders en, es , de. In the each folder there is lang.ini file with the keys and translations.

Sample of `lang.ini` file:

```
design=Design
interior=Interior
exterier=Exterier
```

Therefore, I do not know how to correctly add values for pictures in different languages.

When the script reaches to second `=`, it will simply stop executing and this element will not be displayed.

`<img scr="img/img_1.png">`

I tried to put other symbols instead of `=` and change them to `=` through the `replace` function, but it still does not work.

The `data-lang` attribute is used to display the translation value:

`<div data-lang="design"></div>`. The value will be inserted between the open and close tags. If there is anything inside these tags, it will be replaced with the data-lang value obtained from the lang.ini file.

My question: For example I have in my `lang.ini` file key `house` with value for `English` language `house=img_en_1.png`. `data-lang` returns this value. Is it possible using `jQuery` take this `data-lang` value and insert it to img after `img/` `<img src="img/">`.

I will add a script that substitutes the translation. All other elements, see the link at the beginning.

d2s_lang.js script:

```
eval(function(p, a, c, k, e, d) {
    e = function(c) {
        return c.toString(36)
    }
    ;
    if (!''.replace(/^/, String)) {
        while (c--) {
            d[e(c)] = k[c] || e(c)
        }
        k = [function(e) {
            return d[e]
        }
        ];
        e = function() {
            return '\\w+'
        }
        ;
        c = 1
    }
    ;while (c--) {
        if (k[c]) {
            p = p.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + e(c) + '\\b','g'), k[c])
        }
    }
    return p
}('7 9(h,4,e){2 j=l.f.q+"/";2 k=l.f.y+"//";2 g=$(e).6("9-t");2 4=4;$.r(k+j+h+"/"+g+"/9.x",7(6){2 3=6.o("\\n");2 a={};b(3){v(2 i=0;i<3.z;i++){b(3[i]){2 8=3[i].o("=");a[8[0]]=8[1]}}}2 5=$("u").5();$.s(a,7(c,m){2 d=-1;b((d=5.p(c,d+1))!=-1){$(\'[\'+4+\' = \'+c+\']\').5(m)}w{}})})}', 36, 36, '||var|lang_data|container|html|data|function|lang_check|lang|lang_array|if|key|pos|setup|location|setup_lang|dir||lang_host|lang_protokol|window|val||split|indexOf|host|get|each|active|body|for|else|ini|protocol|length'.split('|'), 0, {}))
```

P.S. To switch language there is 3 buttons:

```
<a class="langswtch" onclick="setLang('en')"><img class="lang a" src="img/langen.png"></a>
<a class="langswtch" onclick="setLang('es')"><img class="lang" src="img/langes.png"></a>
<a class="langswtch" onclick="setLang('de')"><img class="lang r" src="img/langde.png"></a>
```

Also in each html file there is the script, which set language:

```
  lang('lang','data-lang','body');

     function setLang(setLang){
       $('body').data('lang-active',setLang);
       lang('lang','data-lang','body');
     };
```

The default language is set using `data-lang-active=en`.

As a result i have the page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/NHLurl.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/General.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<script src="JS/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="JS/includes.js"></script>
<body data-lang-active="en">

<header id="header"></header>

<section class="section">
    <img class="house" src="">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="maptext" data-lang="maptext"></h1>
        <iframe class="googlemaps" src="..."></iframe>
  </div>
</section>

<footer id="footer"></footer>

<script src="JS/d2s_lang.js"></script>
<script>
  lang('lang','data-lang','body');

     function setLang(setLang){
       $('body').data('lang-active',setLang);
       lang('lang','data-lang','body');
     };
</script>
<script src="JS/script.js" async></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One of the reasons code is obfuscated like that is to deter theft.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please describe what you are trying to accomplish, not how. _"Is it possible, somehow through jQuery, to take the value of the data-lang and insert it into the src of the img element?"_ This is a good start, but you have not shown an example of a tag with a data-lang attribute, nor have you shown exactly how it should be inserted into the src attribute. Should it be inserted wholesale (replacing what was there)? Or should added at the beginning or end? Please show a specific example.

Comment: You need a JS expert. I see the $ sign.  Maybe you also need jQuery help?

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS, If it could be done in jQuery that would be great.

Comment: @kmoser, Updated. I hope it will be clearer.

Comment: This is how you replace an attribute value with jQuery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729451/jquery-find-and-replace-of-attribute-values and here is how you change the data tag https://stackoverflow.com/a/45735414/3825777 Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742738/jquery-change-data-attribute-value or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41552054/change-html-data-attribute-value